# How can I enlarge an image's pixels on OS X?

Tags: macos, images

I have OS X with Preview and OmniGraffle. In both of these apps, resizing an image to make it larger results in heavy anti-aliasing. I want just big pixels. How can I get that effect instead of the anti-aliasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pixen](http://opensword.org/pixen/download.php) from the Open Sword Group is a pixel editor that fulfils your requirements. It is free (donationware), and comes in at 867 kb.

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom using Mac OS X's integrated zoom functionality (usually `Ctrl-Scroll`).

I can configure it in *System Preferences » Trackpad* on my Macbook Pro. It has the option to disable/enable image smoothing, and you can toggle any time by pressing `Cmd-Opt-\`.

[image]

Screenshots created while zooming are zoomed. Unmodified rectangle selection screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer, but it doesn't allow me to resize things super-huge.  I'm actually just dissatisfied that Omnigraffle doesn't have this simple feature.

Comment: @marienbad OmniGraffle is primarily a vector tool. Why should it have extensive pixel image configuration? I am able to enlarge every pixel to 20x20 dimensions -- what's your use case? What do you want to accomplish?